# Memcache in Google App Engine Standard environment for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memcached

I'm writing a webapp in NodeJS and came across a use case where memcached offered by GAE would be of great help for me. I looked in the doc, but it seems that the API support is only for Java and Python, not for NodeJS.

Is there a way to access the shared memcache instance using the standard libraries? My guess is that the instance is somehow exposed?